# How to remove class from Button 1 when clicking on Button 2 - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, loops, event-handling

I am trying to make a highlight effect on Button 1 (bold and blue text with a css class).
But of course the class should be removed from Button 1 when i click on another Button in the Menu.

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".ef-button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

   buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

      if (buttons[i].classList.contains("active-element")) {
         buttons[i].classList.remove("active-element");
      } else {
         buttons[i].classList.add("active-element");
      }

   })

}
```

This is what i wrote. I can click on every button to highlight it, but when i click on another button it does not remove the class from the first button...
Anyways, i can click on a already highlighted button to remove the class again.

What i need is like a "reset" that removes the class from the button i clicked on.

[image]

When i click on Buttons:

[image]

Comment: where is your HTML/CSS?

Comment: [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is what you needed.

Comment: Is it necessary? I just add the class .active-element with "color: blue" and "font-weight: bold" :D

Comment: @Hauskamel, people can understand your question easily and they may use your HTML and create an example for you to reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this way:
[*for those who want to avoid searching in the MDN Doc1*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

```js
document
.querySelectorAll('.ef-button')
.forEach( (btClickEv,_,buttons) =>
  {
  btClickEv.onclick = () =>
    buttons.forEach(bt=>bt.classList.toggle('active-element',bt===btClickEv))
  })
```

```css
.ef-button       { background : pink; }
.active-element  { background : green; }
```

```html
<button class="ef-button"> bt1 </button> 
<button class="ef-button"> bt2 </button> 
<button class="ef-button"> bt3 </button> 
<button class="ef-button"> bt4 </button> 
<button class="ef-button"> bt4 </button>
```

Comment: I didn't know that we can pass `toggle` an extra parameter also for conditions.  Great stuff